# What is the purpose of RELATED DAX formula in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to PowerBI and I'm trying to figure out how to improve my skill through some simple tasks found online. One of them asked me to create calculated columns using the formula `RELATED = (table(column))`.

I've done it but I don't understand exactly what's the purpose of this syntax. I mean, all the 4 tables used are already connected in the model, so I could anyway create Matrix or other visual using one field from a table and another field from another table and the results to me looks the same as using the columns made with RELATED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, correct there isn't a need to create a calculated column if you don't need to. But there are times when you do need to create calculated column. And when you start writing expressions and calculations then RELATED and other functions are needed.

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax and see the examples below.

And you might find this an interesting and useful read: [Calculated Columns and Measures in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/)

Comment: thank you! Basically, related does the same as connecting 2 tables in the model via graphic interface, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: Basically, correct. Do note that RELATED only works from a many-to-one or a one-to-one relationship.